# How to test redirects in ComponentWillMount in enzyme/jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am new to testing in Enzyme and Jest.
I want to test my `ComponentWillMount` method, whether certain redirect will happen or not.
Here is the code of my component:

```
class ActivationSF extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.className = 'ActivationSF.js'
    this.state = {
      messages: null,
     }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ActivationUI
        context={this.props.context}
        messages={this.state.messages}
      />
    );
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    let context = this.props.context

    if(!context.userInfo){      
      window.location.replace('/identify')
    }

    let externalLP = ExternalLandingPageUtil.getExternalLandingPageUrl(context);
    if (externalLP) {
      window.location.replace(`${externalLP}`);
      return;
    }

    if (context.userInfo)
    {
       window.location = '/store'
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.body.classList.add('sdp')
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a unit test strategy:

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ExternalLandingPageUtil } from './ExternalLandingPageUtil';
import { ActivationUI } from './ActivationUI';

export class ActivationSF extends Component<any, any> {
  public className: string;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.className = 'ActivationSF.js';
    this.state = {
      messages: null
    };
  }

  render() {
    return <ActivationUI context={this.props.context} messages={this.state.messages} />;
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    let context = this.props.context;

    if (!context.userInfo) {
      window.location.replace('/identify');
    }

    let externalLP = ExternalLandingPageUtil.getExternalLandingPageUrl(context);
    if (externalLP) {
      window.location.replace(`${externalLP}`);
      return;
    }

    if (context.userInfo) {
      window.location.replace('/store');
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.body.classList.add('sdp');
  }
}
```

`ActivationUI.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';

export const ActivationUI = ({ context, messages }) => <div>ActivationUI</div>;
```

`ExternalLandingPageUtil.ts`:

```js
export const ExternalLandingPageUtil = {
  getExternalLandingPageUrl(context) {
    return context.externalLP;
  }
};
```

`index.spec.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ActivationSF } from './';
import { ExternalLandingPageUtil } from './ExternalLandingPageUtil';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

window.location.replace = jest.fn();

describe('ActivationSF', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  test('should redirect to /identify', () => {
    const mProps = { context: {} };
    const wrapper = shallow(<ActivationSF {...mProps}></ActivationSF>);
    expect(window.location.replace).toBeCalledWith('/identify');
  });
  test('should redirect to external IP address', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(ExternalLandingPageUtil, 'getExternalLandingPageUrl');
    const mProps = { context: { userInfo: {}, externalLP: '10.0.0.1' } };
    const wrapper = shallow(<ActivationSF {...mProps}></ActivationSF>);
    expect(window.location.replace).toBeCalledWith('10.0.0.1');
    expect(spy).toBeCalledWith(mProps.context);
  });
  test('should redirect to /store', () => {
    const mProps = { context: { userInfo: {} } };
    const wrapper = shallow(<ActivationSF {...mProps}></ActivationSF>);
    expect(window.location.replace).toBeCalledWith('/store');
  });

  test('should render correctly', () => {
    const mProps = { context: {} };
    const addSpy = jest.spyOn(document.body.classList, 'add');
    const wrapper = shallow(<ActivationSF {...mProps}></ActivationSF>);
    expect(wrapper.prop('context')).toEqual(mProps.context);
    expect(wrapper.state('messages')).toBeNull();
    expect(addSpy).toBeCalledWith('sdp');
    addSpy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage for `ActivationSF` component.

```sh
PASS  src/stackoverflow/57673447/index.spec.tsx (12.286s)
  ActivationSF
    ✓ should redirect to /identify (14ms)
    ✓ should redirect to external IP address (2ms)
    ✓ should redirect to /store (1ms)
    ✓ should render correctly (2ms)

----------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File                        |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files                   |    90.32 |      100 |    85.71 |      100 |                   |
 ActivationUI.tsx           |       40 |      100 |        0 |      100 |                   |
 ExternalLandingPageUtil.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.tsx                  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       4 passed, 4 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        14.412s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57673447